# Is it possible to change username and all configuration (filenames, ...) for Windows user?

Tags: windows

I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10, and when I first started it 2 years ago, it asked me for my name to set up default user. My name is Róbert (notice the ó).

Now, in my file system I have C:\Users\Róbert. Seems neat. However, over the years I became somewhat of a coder, and the weird letter ó started causing some problems. It first happened when I started using Android Studio and Java, more recently (today) when I reinstalled Anaconda (distribution for Python).

I am sure it was problem with the ó, because it throws errors like `can't read non-ascii character 0xf3` and so on.

Is there a way to solve this (reconfigure everything)? I believe setting up a new user is a possibility, but I would prefer other solution.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what version of Windows you are using

Comment: For any modern system, changing the name on the user profile may be tricky.  Did you decide to try?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of the user folder can be tricky.  See this article:

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-account-name-windows-10/

Note the warning:

> Renaming it can be risky—sometimes sticking with it or just creating a
>   new user account then copying your files to the new account is a
>   better option. Yes, it’s annoying, but its better than ending up with
>   a corrupt user profile

You may truly be better to make a new User Profile and that is what I recommend